# Porting an iOS app to OSX and maintaining one code set?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I'm an experienced iOS developer but have not touched OSX development. I plan to port my iOS app to OSX. Of course, there will be certain differences based upon the obvious design paradigm and differences in SDKs, but I could easily see 80-90% of the code being identical, even including a lot of the UI. Is there any good approach for maintaining one code set that powers both apps? Of course, I could do some sort of static library, but I'm wondering if there is a complete solution, and/or advice on what pitfalls I might encounter as a new OSX developer...

Comment: This question really is a good one but a very open one as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://chameleonproject.org/, "a drop in replacement for UIKit that runs on Mac OS X".

Alternatively, you could have two different targets in your Xcode project, one for iOS and the other for Mac, then include the overlapping code files in both your iOS and Mac targets.

Comment: This looks great so far. Of course, I'll need to spend a lot of time with it before I know if it is a full solution, but the combination of Chameleon and a 2nd target sounds like a perfect solution (in theory)...